# Can I connect Mongoose to a sharded MongoDB instance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose@4.2.6, I want to connect to a sharded MongoDB instance.

```
const url = "mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27022,localhost:27023/db";

// This never resolves
Mongoose.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    ...
});
```

When I make the connection using the native MongoDB@2.0.48 library (the same version used by Mongoose), it works.

```
const url = "mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27022,localhost:27023/db";

// This resolves a connection
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    ...
});
```

When I make the connection in Mongoose, the connect callback never resolves.

Is there something in Mongoose that I have to configure to allow me to connect to a sharded Mongo instance?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @BlakesSeven the mongoose connect callback never resolves. Have figured it out now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to pass an object in as the second argument, with the value mongos = true

```
const url = "mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27022,localhost:27023/db";

// This now resolves
Mongoose.connect(url, { mongos: true }, (err, db) => {
    ...
});
```

It's not terribly clear from the docs, but it is there - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html